# Is there a way to make this code less long but do the same thing?

Tags: python, loops, counting

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence?")
sentence=sentence.capitalize()
counta = sentence.count("a")
counte = sentence.count("e")
counti = sentence.count("i")
counto= sentence.count ("o")
countu= sentence.count ("u")
countA2 = sentence.count("A")
countE2 = sentence.count("E")
countI2 = sentence.count("I")
countO2 = sentence.count("O")
countU2 = sentence.count("U")
countI3 = sentence.count(" I ")
countspaces = sentence.count(" ")
a1 = sentence.count("!")
a2 = sentence.count(".")
a3 = sentence.count(">")
a4 = sentence.count("<")
a5 = sentence.count(":")
a6= sentence.count(";")
a7 = sentence.count("'")
a8 = sentence.count("@")
a9 = sentence.count("#")
a10 = sentence.count("~")
a11= sentence.count("{")
a12= sentence.count("}")
a13= sentence.count("[")
a14 = sentence.count("]")
a15 = sentence.count("-")
a16 = sentence.count("_")
a17 = sentence.count("+")
a18 = sentence.count("=")
a19 = sentence.count("£")
a20 = sentence.count("$")
a21= sentence.count("%")
a22 = sentence.count("^")
a23= sentence.count("&")
a24 = sentence.count("(")
a25= sentence.count(")")
a26=sentence.count("?")
count = (counta + counte + counti + counto + countu + countA2 + countE2 +     countI2 + countO2 + countU2 + countI3)
speci= a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8+a9+a10+a11+a12+a13+a14+a15+a16+a17+a18+a19+a20+a21+a22+a23+a24+a25+a26)
print(sentence)
print("This has", speci, "special characters")
print("This has", countspaces, "Spaces")
print("This has", count, "vowels")
```

The above code as you can see is waaayyy too long. I dont know how to do the same thing (which is user inputs sentence and it counts vowels, spaces and special characters) but in less lines of code. If you know a better way. Please tell me. Because of course coding is all about the best code and this looks way to weird to be the best way.
Thanks for your help

Comment: That is an excellent thing to wish to do.  There are many people who are ready to give improvements, but they hang out at [codereview.se].  Good luck there!  It is also a good idea to give a description of what your code does so that they can review it better.

Comment: Note that I would start by having a string for each of your cases (e.g. `vowels = 'aeiou'`) and make it iterate over the input (`for char in sentence.lower():`) rather than the current implicit iteration over the characters you're looking for.

Comment: Also, note the result of `from collections import Counter` then `Counter('Here is an example sentence')`, which may be of use.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: ` "I" in " I "` == True, wrong count...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for special characters do:

```
special_char = 0
for i in sentence:
    if i.isalpha() == False and i.isdigit() == False:
        special_char += 1
```

For spaces:

```
spaces = sentence.count(' ')
```

For vowels, make a dictionary with vowels as keys, and then go through the whole input and perform a match with the individual keys from the vowels dict.

Answer (score 0):

One loop to rule em all:

```
sentence = raw_input()
vowels = special_char = spaces = 0
for letter in sentence.lower():
    if letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
        vowels += 1
    elif letter == ' ':
        spaces += 1
    elif not (letter.isalpha() or letter.isdigit()):
        special_char += 1
print("Vowels: {},Spaces: {},Special Chars: {}".format(vowels,spaces,special_char))
```

Comment: It returns a invalid syntax : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10
    print "Vowels: {},Spaces: {},Special Chars: {}".format(vowels,spaces,special_char)
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The `print` statement runs fine on my machine. Are you using Python 3? I've made an edit and hopefully it will not raise a syntax error now. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the solutions, you have probably made up your mind already. Just to shorten it down by selecting the individual characters you want to use, try this code below.

```
word = "banana"
characters = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
for letter in word:
    if letter in characters:
        print("Special character.")
```

Just of course add more characters to the list using the same way that I've added the vowels in.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you like list comprehension :

```
sentence = raw_input("What is your sentence ? ")
print "Vowels : " + str(len([i for i in sentence if i.lower() in ('a','e','i','o','u')]))
print "Spaces : " + str(sentence.count(' '))
print "Special Chars : " + str(len([i for i in sentence if (not i.isalpha() and not i.isdigit() and not i.isspace())]))
```